# Power on the device with an alarm in Android

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

Is there any way to "Power on" the device in case some alarm happens ?. This was available in old Nokia phones when you set an alarm , if the device is OFF , the devices goes on at the alarm time, then goes OFF again. Can we have this in Android ? . I'm not talking about waking up the device while sleeping, I need to power it on if he is OFF and have battery power.

Thanks alot

Comment: When you shut down an Android device it stays **off**, so no. [This](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35624/schedule-auto-shutdown-on-android/35625#35625) is also related.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with android because once your device is shut down, the OS isn't running until the device is manually switched on.

However, with root access you can schedule a system shutdown with an alarm but you'll need a rooted device which can void your warranty.

Comment: Thanks Coder. How to do this in rooted device ? and How Nokia is doing it :D

Comment: Search on Google Play for Timerandroid. You need root but it schedules a shutdown for you.